# How to read and parse an XML file only once on first page load instead of on each page request

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset

I must not understand it well enough.
I have created a static class like this:

```
public static class oDs
{
    public static DataSet columnsxml
    {
        get
        {
            DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
            oDs.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Columns.xml"));
            return oDs;
        }

    }
}
```

which is used in the Page_Load class like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in oDs.columnsxml.Tables[0].AsEnumerable())
{
    MyCode()
}
```

My expectation was that since I made class oDs static, it wouldn't keep reading the XML file on every single page request, but that turns out to be false. If I make changes to the XML during runtime, the next page request will have the updated info. I am concerned about the performance impact of this.
Do I have to also do the MyCode() in the static class?

Edit: I am aware of Enterprise Library, but would prefer to do it without that caching.

Comment: do a google search there are so many examples here on `SO` show some more effort please

Comment: the code I am using is partially based on an example I have found, but it just in practice doesn't work.

Comment: @regeter is your only problem that it runs on every postback? if so that's an easy fix

Comment: No, I haven't tested postback yet, I would think if I fix the new request that postbacks would automatically also not rerun the code that creates the dataset.

Comment: @regeter what exactly do you mean by page request then?

Comment: doesn't postback mean that you basically return some user input back to the page?
new page request to me is another user that click onto the link that takes them to this specific page.

Comment: Do an if/else condition on your page load as per your criteria.....

Comment: I cannot just do an if/else, the code needs to run, otherwise the page is blank. The code generates the ASP.NET fields for a GridView. What columns I show in the gridview doesn't really change, but I cannot hardcode it either as the website will be used for different customers that may not want certain fields.

Comment: @regeter ahh sorry I misunderstood you I guess. So you want to only run this code once, and then if a new user comes to the page, you want to use the same data that you already got for another user again?

Comment: @regeter sounds like you need to cache your result output, store the output somewhere and then just redisplay it to different user when he accesses the page.

Comment: @regeter I agree with rex, I personally do not know of another way to handle something like that.

Comment: @regeter best bet would be to output the query results as an xml file and rebind from server as datasource, also gotta check the file is created fresh each time you run the query and delete the old file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on your goal. If the content of the file is static, meaning it is not changed during your application lifecycle, then you can change your static class a little bit this way:

```
public static class oDs
{
    private static DataSet _oDs;

    public static DataSet columnsxml
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oDs == null)
            {
                _oDs = new DataSet();
                _oDs.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Columns.xml"));
            }
            return _oDs;
        }

    }
}
```

Please, be aware that this code is not tread-safe, so you'll probably want to add a lock there.

The other choice would be to use the Application_Start event in Global.asax to load the file content upon application startup.

Comment: Thanks Ronnix. I am getting error "A get or set accessor expected" on the line:
private static DataSet _oDs;

Comment: @Rex - because IIS creates a separate thread for each request. So if two request arrive simultaneously, the server will process them at the same time using separate threads from the ThreadPool.

Comment: @regeter - Sorry, basically I did not check if the code can be compiled. I've fixed my answer (the declaration of _oDs must be done within the body of the class, not of the property :)

Comment: @Ronnix exactly, IIS handles threading and it is not advisable to explicitly define threading on a webform

Comment: @Rex what are you talking about ? Please show me in my answer, where I _defined_ threading... ?

Comment: So this code is basically a Simple Singleton Pattern?
I will test this out. Thanks.

Comment: Code works well. Will attempt to use the Singleton code from here though: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx Fourth version